# C: Equivalent of pthread_barrier_t for windows

Tags: c, barrier

As per title, is there an equivalent of `pthread_barrier_t` type in windows? I' ve found `SYNCHRONIZATION_BARRIER` but seems available only since Windows 8.

Is there something more portable?

Thanks

Comment: You could do it the old fashioned way before barriers were invented: with a counting semaphore.

Comment: @cup Thanks, please add your comment as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it the old fashioned way before barriers were invented: with a counting semaphore